# How do I write a class that uses objects of another class and puts them in a set?

Tags: python, class

This is for an assignment.
So there are two classes. The first is Student, which creates Students with a Name, an Username and the semester theyre in. I got the first class to work pretty effortlessly, but the second one calles UniClass is hard to do. It creates a University class and gives it a name.
Then it can enroll Students into the class. It is supposed to put them into a set. If it is empty the method "str" shall return "set()" and if not then it shall return the set.

```
class Student:
    def __init__(self,name,imt_name,semester):
        """
        Constructor
        """
        self.name=name
        self.imt_name=imt_name
        self.semester=semester
    def __str__(self):
        """
        """
        return ("{} [{}] in Semester {}".
                format(self.name,
                       self.imt_name,
                       self.semester))
class UniClass:
    def __init__(self,name):
        """
        Constructor
        """
        self.name=name
    def enroll_student(self,students):
        self.students=Student.str()
        global x
        x=True
    def __str__(self):
        if x==True:
            return (students) 
        else:
            return("set()")
```

I messed up at the second class.

Comment: *Do not use `global`.*  **Ever**, if you can possibly help it, at least until you've spent long enough writing code to be able to identify the cases where its benefits as a shortcut outweigh its drawbacks.  For some reason, beginner Python programmers always get told use `global` to fix some early problem, and they then spend the next three years *unlearning* the habit of using `global` every time they're not sure how to pass some piece of state from one part of their program to another.  It's completely counterproductive and in this case it's just negating the purpose of defining a class.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I presume `UniClass` maintains a set of `Student` objects, which means it's the responsibility of whoever calls `UniClass.enroll_student` to *provide* an instance of `Student`, rather than `enroll_student` needing to create a new student. Something like

```
class UniClass:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.students = set()

    def enroll_student(self, student):
        self.students.add(student)

    def __str__(self):
        return ",".join(str(s) for s in self.students)

c = UniClass("math")
c.enroll_student(Student("john", "doe", "fall"))
c.enroll_student(Student("alice", "smith", "fall"))
```